# Как программно сделать вкладку tabcontrol'а неактивной?

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вкладку табконтрола неактивной?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, чтобы "Вкладка2" была неактивной и некликабельной (название вкладки серым цветом, итд).

Свойство **Enabled = false** не подходит, ибо оно просто выключает все контролы на вкладке, но позволяет кликать на неё и просматривать содержимое.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устанавливаем для нужной вкладки `Enabled = false`. И в сочетании со следующим обработчиком события получаем желаемое поведение.

```
private void TabControl_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !e.TabPage.Enabled;
}
```

Чтобы текст заголовка вкладки стал серым, нужно вручную его отрисовывать. Для этого устанавливаем `tabControl.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;` и в событии `DrawItem` рисуем. Примеры найти не составит труда.

Смотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/418006/5045688).